# How to upgrade the go version in a go mod

Tags: go, go-modules

What is the proper way to upgrade the go version in a go mod, specifically 1.13 to 1.14?
Do you simply edit the go.mod file and change `go 1.13` to `go 1.14`?

I'm not asking about *how* to edit the go.mod file, I'm asking if it is proper to simply change the go version in the go.mod file, and everything else (all the dependencies) is still ok for the project?

Comment: Edit the file by hand or use `go mod edit -go=1.14`.

Comment: Thanks! So it is just change "go 1.13" to "go 1.14"?  That's all there is to it? No need to run go mod tidy or any updates?

Comment: If you can simply change the go version whenever you wish with no ramifications, what is it for?  Why is it in the go.mod file?

Comment: It specifies a minimum Go version for the project. If the build fails, the error output will indicate that the module specifies a newer version that was used to try to build it.

Comment: It doesn't do anything else, so the question is kind of moot. It has nothing to do with `go mod tidy` or any of the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Adrian... on digging further, I found this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30791.  Apparently I just don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 100):

[Command go: Edit go.mod from tools or scripts:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Edit_go_mod_from_tools_or_scripts)

> Usage:
>
> ```
> go mod edit [editing flags] [go.mod]
> ```
>
> Edit provides a command-line interface for editing go.mod, for use primarily by tools or scripts. It reads only go.mod; it does not look up information about the modules involved. By default, edit reads and writes the go.mod file of the main module, but a different target file can be specified after the editing flags.
>
> ...
>
> The -go=version flag sets the expected Go language version.

So simply:

```
go mod edit -go=1.14
```

But you may also edit `go.mod` manually, it's a simple text file. `go mod edit` is primilary for scripts so making changes to `go.mod` can easily be automated.

Comment: with the go tool it's `go mod edit -go 1.19`.  `-go=1.19` gave me an error.

Comment: @meblum That depends on the shell you're using.

Answer (score 19):

The answers supplied here helped me alot. But a little adjustment may be due especially for Windows users.

I used on the command prompt:

`go mod edit -go 1.17`

And not:

`go mod edit -go=1.17`

Note the omission of ''=" sign.

Answer (score 15):

The other answer is good, but as another method, say you have this:

```
module north

go 1.13
```

you can just delete the `go` line, and run `go mod tidy`. Result:

```
module north

go 1.16
```

https://golang.org/cmd/go#hdr-Add_missing_and_remove_unused_modules

Comment: I like the answer it's easier and cleaner

Comment: I think this is better because the command will automatically use whichever Go version you have on your machine.

Answer (score 13):

This is how I have done it

```
go mod edit -go 1.18
go mod tidy
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the provided solutions for updating `go.mod` file,

If your project is dockerized, don't forget to update the docker base image as well, e.g.:

```
FROM golang:1.17 AS build
```

to

```
FROM golang:1.20 AS build
```

Answer (score 0):

I you are working with `go.work` you can do it with this script. It will change all child mod version also

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function to recursively upgrade Go modules
upgrade_go_modules() {
  # Prompt user for Go version
  read -p "Enter the Go version (e.g., 1.17): " go_version
  if [ -z "$go_version" ]; then
    echo "Go version not provided. Exiting."
    exit 1
  fi

  # Update go.work file in the root directory
  sed -i "s/go[[:space:]]\+[0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)*$/go $go_version/" go.work

  # Upgrade Go modules
  for mod_file in $(find . -name "go.mod"); do
    dir=$(dirname "$mod_file")
    echo "Updating Go version in $dir"
    (cd "$dir" && go mod edit -go="$go_version")
  done
}

# Main execution
upgrade_go_modules
```