# conversion of slices to array pointers only supported as of -lang=go1.17

Tags: go

I attempted to use the new conversion of slice to array in Go, but I get  a very confusing error message:

```
func TestName(t *testing.T) {
    a := [100]int{}

    b := a[10:50]
    _ = b
    fmt.Println(runtime.Version())

    c := (*[100]int)(b)
}
```

```
sh-3.2$ go test
# 
./....go: cannot convert b (type []int) to type *[100]int:
        conversion of slices to array pointers only supported as of -lang=go1.17
```

Which is confusing me because `go version` reports 1.17.6.

Why is it complaining about something that is supposedly introduced in the version it is using?

Is `-lang=go1.17` supposed to be a flag I can/must pass? it doesn't seem to do anything if I try it.

Edit: I now realise it would have panicked anyway, but that's not really the point of the question.

Comment: The error could be caused by the Go version in `go.mod` being lower than 1.17. Also note that that conversion isn't valid anyway because the array length (100) is greater than the slice's (40)

Comment: It could also be this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44976

Comment: Run `go mod edit -go=1.17`, see [How to upgrade the go version in a go mod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675415/how-to-upgrade-the-go-version-in-a-go-mod/60675491#60675491)

Comment: @blackgreen it was go.mod. If you want to put that in an answer I'll give it the tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-lang` flag is an option of the Go compiler.

It is usually set by `go` commands that compile sources, e.g. `go build`, based on the `go <version>` directive in `go.mod`. You likely have a version in `go.mod` lower than 1.17, which is the version that introduces conversion from slice to array pointers.

You can fix the Go version in `go.mod` by hand or by running `go mod edit -go=1.17`.

As a matter of fact, if you leave `go.mod` with the wrong version (assuming that was the culprit) and invoke the compiler directly with the appropriate flag, it will compile:

```
go tool compile -lang go1.17 ./**/*.go
```

PS: even if it compiles, the conversion in your program will panic because the array length (100) is greater than the slice length (40).