# how to solve "stderr: go mod tidy: go.mod file indicates go 1.17, but maximum supported version is 1.16 ." error?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am getting error on Visual Studio Code:

> Command 'gopls.tidy' failed: Error: err: exit status 1: stderr: go mod tidy: go.mod file indicates go 1.17, but maximum supported version is 1.16 .

I can't fix it with `go mod tidy` and `go mod init`. How can I solve this?

Comment: I believe this is because you are running Go v1.16 locally, but your go.mod file requests that you have at least v1.17. So update your go version or change the go.mod file. But be aware that v1.17 code may not work for your v1.16 install, hence this error

Comment: can I change go.mod version? if I can, how?

Comment: @srls01 check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675415/how-to-upgrade-the-go-version-in-a-go-mod

Answer (score 32):

A simple command in the terminal helped me:

```
brew upgrade go
```

GoLang has been updated, I have restarted the project, and everything is working

Answer (score 25):

If you are using IntelliJ or GoLand built-in terminal, change `GOROOT` on this page:

[image: screenshot]

then restart the IDE.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error in Goland and solved it by restarting the IDE. May also work in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

This issue occurs when your GOROOT and/or you GOTOOLDIR and/or your GOVERSION environment indicates a lower version than the one defined in you `.mod` file.

To check, run `go env` in the terminal within vscode:

```bash
# in my own case:
go env
...
GOROOT="/home/me/sdk/go1.18.1"
...
GOTOOLDIR="/home/me/sdk/go1.18.1/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
...
GOVERSION="go1.18.1"
...
```

where my `.mod` indicates `go 1.19`, so `go mod tidy` prints the error.

To change your current go version in vscode:
`CRTL+P` `>` and enter `go:choose go environment`

or click on the go version on the status bar
[image]

then choose the right one, for me go1.19.1.

VScode ask you to reload Windows

[image]

but even if you click to reload, the go environement variables are not updated! The only way I found is to close VSCode and to REOpen it, that'it.

By doing so, VSCode setup the go environment variables to the one you've choosen to make your development.

Hope this can help

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on GoLand, hopefully it helps someone in the same situation:

You can check and update the version it's using on Preferences -> Go -> GOROOT
[image]

And if you are using a terminal, remember to close it and open it again.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted go and installed again then problem is solved.

Comment: Did you try to use 'brew upgrade go' command instead of deleting?

Answer (score 1):

I solved thisby using https://go.dev/doc/manage-install, to change my current version of golang (1.16), and set the version that the project needs, then set my GOROOT and PATH of go, with the new version and then run `go mod tidy`

Answer (score 0):

This is the error i got:

```
go mod tidy: go.mod file indicates go 1.18, but maximum supported version is 1.17
```

My GOROOT was 1.18 but somehow my it seems changed to 1.17 version. I think Goland misguided and in your case it could be VSCode.

Anyway, i changed my GOROOT sdk version to 1.18 and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Sergei, the command `brew upgrade go` will not always work if your brew setup is outdated. I faced a similar issue where I was using go 1.19 and wanted to upgrade to version go 1.21.

When I used `brew upgrade go`, it already said that my go 1.19 is already updated to latest.

```
Warning: go 1.19.3 already installed
```

However, on Homebrew - the formulae seems to be having latest go 1.21 version https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/go. To make sure, you've successfully installed an updated go version using brew - first update brew and then upgrade go.

```bash
brew update
brew upgrade go
```

Verify update go version using command `go version`

If you're using Goland IDE, you'll have to make sure that you've updated GOROOT environment variable to use latest go version. I'm attaching a screenshot for example purpose.

[image: goland screenshot updating GOROOT to use latest go version]

After making this change, make sure to restart your terminal, so that it will pick the latest go version.

Answer (score -1):

you can also change the go version to 1.18 or whichever it complains about, then run `go mod tidy` and then change it back to what the go version was before